# Get rid of blank result from reg_ex_split_table output

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, greatest-n-per-group, lateral-join

I have a query that counts all of the words in one column and gives me the frequency and frequency rank of the word as the result. For some reason, I keep getting a row that has no word in it. How do I get rid of it?

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE dummy (
created_at TIMESTAMPTZ,
tweet TEXT);
```

Insert:

```
INSERT INTO dummy VALUES ('2020-12-18 00:00:00+00', 'foo squared');
INSERT INTO dummy VALUES ('2020-12-18 00:00:00+00', 'foo foo');
INSERT INTO dummy VALUES ('2020-12-18 00:00:00+00', 'foo foo');
INSERT INTO dummy VALUES ('2020-12-18 00:00:00+00', 'foo bar');
```

Query:

```
select *
from (
    select date_trunc('day', created_at) as created_day, word, count(*) as cnt,
        rank() over(partition by date_trunc('day', created_at) order by count(*) desc) rn
    from dummy d
    cross join lateral regexp_split_to_table(
        regexp_replace(tweet, '\y(rt|co|https|bar|none)\y', '', 'g'),
        '\s+'
    ) w(word)
    group by created_day, word
) d
where created_day = CURRENT_DATE and word IS NOT NULL
order by rn
LIMIT 10;
```

Returns:

```
      created_day       |  word   | cnt | rn
------------------------+---------+-----+----
 2020-12-18 00:00:00+00 | foo     |   4 |  1
 2020-12-18 00:00:00+00 |         |   2 |  2
 2020-12-18 00:00:00+00 | arm     |   1 |  3
 2020-12-18 00:00:00+00 | squared |   1 |  3
```

I'd like to get rid of the blank word:

```
      created_day       |  word   | cnt | rn
------------------------+---------+-----+----
 2020-12-18 00:00:00+00 | foo     |   4 |  1
 2020-12-18 00:00:00+00 | arm     |   1 |  2
 2020-12-18 00:00:00+00 | squared |   1 |  3
```

Comment: Are you able to provide a minimum reproducible example so one can investigate the issue? Also, seeing that you are going for a new question, I would recommend accepting an answer on [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65354100/get-ranking-of-words-over-date-based-on-frequency-in-postgresql).

Comment: Apologies, I've updated the question to include a reproducible example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the inner `regexp_replace()`; when the matching part is at the end of the string, you end up with a trailing space at the end of the strings. Basically, when applied to `'foo bar'`, it generates `'foo '`.

Then when parsed, this generates a final word whose value is the empty string (`''`).

A simple workaround is to `trim()` the output of `regexp_replace()`, so basically replace:

```
cross join lateral regexp_split_to_table(
    regexp_replace(tweet, '\y(rt|co|https|bar|none)\y', '', 'g'),
    '\s+'
) w(word)
```

With:

```
cross join lateral regexp_split_to_table(
    trim(regexp_replace(tweet, '\y(rt|co|https|bar|none)\y', '', 'g')),
    '\s+'
) w(word)
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=2d211ad3bf269a120b332d5aeedf9312)**

Answer (score 0):

Can you use it in `where` clause?

```
where created_day = CURRENT_DATE 
  And word is not null -- this
order by rn;
```

Or you can use same condition here also.

```
) w(word)
word is not null -- this
group by created_day, word
```

Comment: I tried that but unfortunately, I still get the same result